# Out-of-box solution for Android for guaranteed delivery of http requests

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I have an Android application that has a screen for displaying information about any user of the service for which mobile application was developed. Users are able to subscribe to other users on that screen.

Current solution with Rx and Retrofit works fine but when user leave the screen I clear disposables and then the http call under the hood of Retrofit is being canceled. So if user leaves the screen his operation on it (such as subscribing or likinng/disliking) get lost.

I want to keep that requests which modify some data (usually POST-request) and send them until backend of my application will receive it and send a response. Moreover I want to persist that request on disk to survive the app's process death. It means that if user leaves screen and system kills my app then after it launched again it will perform an attempt to send saved requests. Of course if there is an internet connection.

I wonder if out-of-box solution for that purposes exists. I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Workmanager can be used to schedule this kind of request.